# ServiceManager returns same Instance while shared = false

Tags: dependency-injection, zend-framework2

I defined an alias for `MyClass` that I want to be retrievable via ServiceManager, see `module.config.php` example below. When I retrieve an instance of `MyClass` in my controller via `$this->serviceLocator->get('MyClass')` I get a new instane the first time, and then the same instance. Do I miss something in my configuration or should I file a bug?

```
module.config.php
return array(
    'di' => array(
        'instance' => array(
            'alias' => array(
                'MyClass' => 'Some\Namespace\MyClass',
            ),

            'MyClass' => array(
                'shared' => false,
             ),                 
         ),
    ),
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As my edit was not accepted, I will answer this question myself. In the end I moved to `ServiceManager` thanks to Stoyan Dimov who pushed me into the right direction. Unfortunately his answer was not correct. I had to use `invokables` instead of `alias`. Here is the correct example:

```
return array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'MyClass' => 'Some\Namespace\MyClass',
    ),

    'shared' => array(
        'MyClass' => false,
    ),
);
```

When I was using `alias` instead of `invokables` I got an `exception` that no service with that name can be is available, which means that `alias`does not work, there has to be an existing service defined by `invokables`, `factories`, `services` or `abstract_factories`.

Following the previous example I could use:

```
...
'alias' => array(
    'SomethingDifferent' => 'MyClass',
),
...
```

With a call to `$this->serviceLocator->get('SomethingDifferent')`I would receive an instance of `Some\Namespace\MyClass`.

Comment: Your edit was rejected as you are not supposed to modify code in other peoples answers unless fixing formatting etc. Posting a new answer as you have done now is your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the `DI` but the `ServiceManager` expects your to specify `shared` (false) in the root of the configuration array for the manager. Something like this:

```
'invokables' => array( // Note that you can use also 'factories', 'abstract_factories', etc.
     'Some\Namespace\MyClass' => 'Some\Namespace\MyClass',
),
'alias' => array(
    'MyClass' => 'Some\Namespace\MyClass',
),
'shared' => array(
    'MyClass' => false,
),
```

See the `ServiceManager` example configuration on the manual

Hope this helps :)

Stoyan

Comment: If no other good answer is available I will consider refactoring to use the ServiceManager

Comment: I edited your answer, as it wasn't working, if it goes through I will accept it.